# Intuitive explanation of this conditional probability identity

Tags: probability-theory

We've known this equation since infancy:

$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B\mid A)$

and I know how to interpret the LHS as a Venn diagram. But how does one interpret the RHS? What does it mean? I'm not asking for a formal or algebraic proof, but an explanation. Something like a counting argument.

Comment: My interpretation would be LHS = probability that both $A$ and $B$ occur. RHS = probability that $A$ occurs and then $B$ occurs after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This equation is a sort of probabilistic version of the multiplication principle (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)).
The right hand side first takes the probability that $A$ occurs, and then multiplies it by the probability that $B$ occurs given that $A$ occurs.

I feel that it would be better to instead interpret the definition of conditional probability, which is
$$
P(B \mid A) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}.
$$
If $S$ denotes the sample space, then
$$
P(B \mid A) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)} = \frac{|A\cap B|/|S|}{|A|/|S|}=\frac{|A\cap B|}{|A|}.
$$
Now we've unwrapped the definition to obtain:
$$
P(B \mid A) = \frac{|A\cap B|}{|A|}.
$$
This is similar to the definition $P(A)=|A|/|S|$. When we are working with the assumption that $A$ has occurred in $P(B\mid A)$, the event $A$ becomes our "new" sample space (since we restrict our attention only to $A$), and so in order to compute the probability of $B$ under this assumption, we need to count $|A\cap B|$ and then divide by $|A|$. We intersect $B$ with $A$ in the numerator to ensure that we don't count any outcomes that don't lie in $A$ - our "new" sample space.